# OKHTTP: How to measure total bytes in Request and Response?

Tags: java, okhttp

Were using `okhttp3` to `POST` a `JSON` payload to a web server.  We want to know the total byte count of the request and the response for the `POST` request.  Ultimately, we want to get the data throughput.  Here is the code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .post(body)
    .build();    
mBytesSent += request.body.contentLength();  // Payload byte count
mBytesSent += request.headers().size();
mBytesSent += request.tag().toString().length();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()  

mBytesRecd += response.body().contentLength();
mBytesRecd += response.headers().toString().length();
mBytesRecd += response.message().length();
```

Is this the complete byte count for a `POST`?

Comment: What do these methods `request.tag().toString().length()` and `response.message().length()` return?

Comment: Technically, excluding underlying TCP headers(s), the `headers + body` would give you the total bytes count.

Comment: Is there a dedicated call to return total bytes sent or received?

Comment: you could put a proxy/ man in middle like  Pipe Server https://github.com/QuickServerLab/QuickServer-Examples or jmeter recorder to check

Comment: The reason that I ask this question is that we are finding 5x more traffic through the LTE Data Connection than is accounted for with this estimate.  I'm searching for the descrepancy.  Is there a way to get access to Androids transport Sent/Recd counter?

Comment: @Hephaestus: Well, in that case, you should be using `Wireshark` or `tcpdump` to sniff and analyze data. At request / response level, your best bet is to sum the `length`s of `headers().toString()` and `body().toString()`. Plus, you can log all the requests / responses pairs and then compare those on server. If you have some trusted clients then it would be quite easy to distinguish those from the rest.

Comment: You may use the `interceptors` for logging. See: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with an estimate, you can use EventListener for this

https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/events/

https://github.com/google/horologist/blob/main/network-awareness/src/main/java/com/google/android/horologist/networks/okhttp/impl/NetworkLoggingEventListenerFactory.kt#L98-L120

```
        override fun requestHeadersEnd(call: Call, request: Request) {
            bytesTransferred += request.headers.byteCount()
        }

        override fun requestBodyEnd(call: Call, byteCount: Long) {
            bytesTransferred += byteCount
        }

        override fun responseHeadersEnd(call: Call, response: Response) {
            bytesTransferred += response.headers.byteCount()
        }

        override fun responseBodyEnd(call: Call, byteCount: Long) {
            bytesTransferred += byteCount
        }
```

Comment: requestBodyEnd and responseBodyEnd always returning ZERO

Comment: Are you posting a body? or receiving a non zero body? If so, raise a bug with a reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the code in HttpLoggingInterceptor which buffers streaming requests and responses to get their size, even when not known ahead of time.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/b97eeacaa31a2c72a9396f5a4eab82f69b39cda8/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt

Comment: new link: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/java/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt

Comment: Links are not working, maybe should be edited with some code examples or with explanation how to get to the useful source code to make it usefull.

Comment: It will work for request / response body and you could still estimate headers size but it won't be accurate. To measure bytes you need to be on a lower level. OkHttp lets you override SocketFactory. You could create a wrapper around a default one returning your Socket classes. These socket classes would be wrap original sockets, but would override getInputStream() and getOuptutStream()...

Comment: Looks like overriding Socket in this way won't work... So far, interceptor that counts body +  `headers.byteCount()` the easiest way, although not accurate...

Comment: @Yuri Still I dont see responseBodyEnd not returning values it always ZERO